# Changing word order in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, fronting

'With no man more than Pope **are** such personal considerations relevant and cogent.'

-History of English Literature, by Edward Albert

Why **are** is used prior to the subject 'such personal constructions relevant and cogent'. I know 'Fronting', where we move prepositional phrase at the start of the sentence to create emphasis. But can we do the same thing with verbs too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how the construction works. When a phrase is moved to the start of the sentence for emphasis, the verb has to change its place as well.

> Only in [this region] *can you* see such spectacular scenery.
>
> Only in the country *do I* feel at peace.